# Unity and C# - Cube with random directions

Tags: unity, c#, ios

I want to create a similar line RigidObject in Unity c# just like in the iOS game Circle:

[image: http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple5/v4/de/12/0f/de120f2c-14a7-57a3-404a-a7d90280c572/screen568x568.jpeg]

So far I placed a cube object that is extended by length.

So, how would you approach to create such an object?

I tried with a for loop where I was trying to add a cube at the end of the other, but the rotation messed everything up.

I don't want to create a prefab, since I want the lines to be random and different every time the player starts the game.

Comment: You could do this in 2D using a LineRenderer, and some BoxColliders.

Comment: but is linerenderer a rigidbody, will it react to collisions?

Comment: Yeah, you can add a rigidbody to each node in your line, if that is how you want to deal with collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Edge Collider to map the collision, and a Line Renderer to render the line. Both of them take an array of points, and will make the line/collider as you specify.